# js file attached with form via ajax twice time not come with form

Tags: theming, hooks

I have attached JS file with form and this form is coming by AJAX. when first call AJAX to get Form, in AJAX response form and JS (attached with form) are coming. but I close form and do not refresh page and again send Ajax call for form, second time form come but JS (attached with form) are not come. this JS file has to run after form for form validation. but second time it not come with form. how solve above problem.

for more information: [click here](http://www.coutallure.com)

1. click on the above link
2. click on "CONTACT US" link, a contact us form will come via Ajax.
3. see in fire bug two files are come form and js file.
4. close it form and do not refresh page, repeat step 2 the form come but JS file is coming the second time.

Question: How to solve the problem?

**Edit**
attached form code:
 `$form['#attached']['js'] = array(
            drupal_get_path('module', 'contact_form_alters') . '/js/contactForm_ClientValidation.js');`

Ajax callback function :

```
//function returns contact form using ajax
function bottombar_contact_form_show($js = NULL) {

  if(!function_exists('contact_site_page')) {
    form_clear_error();
    require_once drupal_get_path('module', 'contact') .'/contact.pages.inc';
    $commands=array();
    $output=  drupal_get_form('contact_site_form');
    $commands[]=  ajax_command_invoke(null, "zeContactUsForm", array(drupal_render($output)));
    $page = array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);
    ajax_deliver($page);
  }
}
```